# Linking a Function(script) to a dropdown selection

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have the script below and I want to be able to display it on a page by selecting an option in a dropdown but I don't know how to link it to the dropdown.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.748441, -73.985664),
zoom:16,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This is the dropdown code:

```
    <div id="top_nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Famous Places
            <ul><a href="Empire State Building.html">Empire State Building</a></li>
            <ul><a href="Eifel Tower.html">Eifel Tower</a></li>
            <ul><a href="Olympic Stadium.html">Olympic Stadium</a></li>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick to an anchor like so

```
<a href="Empire State Building.html" onclick="initialize()">Empire State Building</a>
```

Comment: Ok...what if I wanted to have the script run on the same page and not go to a new page?  I have three dropdowns (scripts) and I want them to be available for a visitor to click from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a onClick event that values the function you want to run